# Как возовбновить стандартное поведение браузера при клике на ссылку?

Tags: javascript

Как возобновить стандартное поведение браузера при клике на ссылку, если оно отменяется кодом выше

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
})
```

нужно обнулить, вернуть до стандартного(этот код пример)

Comment: `$('a').click()`

Comment: Удалите из кода e.preventDefault(); и будет вам счастье.) Данная функция отменяет действие по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 location.href = $(this).attr('href');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  console.log("$('a').on('click'");
  e.preventDefault();
});

function standardBehaviour() {
  console.log("standardBehaviour");
  $('a').off('click');
  $('a')[0].click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>

<button onclick="standardBehaviour()">Click</button>
```